# How to vectorize a recursive relation (AR in Bootstrapping)? Possible?

Tags: regression, time-series, bootstrap

I´m working towards the resolution of all questions in Efron & Tibshirani 1993. The Introduction to the Bootstrap. I got stuck in question 8.6.

It is related to the bootstrap of an AR process, considering residuals, which leads, in each step, to the generation of the bootstrap sample, using

$z^*_2=\hat \beta z_1 + e^*_2$

$z^*_3=\hat \beta z^*_2 + e^*_3$

$\vdots$

$z^*_n=\hat \beta z^*_{n-1} + e^*_n$

The question suggests this process can be implemented using a vectorized approach, starting with $z_1$, $\hat \beta$ and a bootstrap sample from the residuals represented by $e^*_2,\ldots,e^*_n$. I cannot see how. Any idea?

[image: Question 8.6 Efron and Tibshirani 1993. Introduction to the Bootstrap]

Comment: Bootstrap calculations usually require many sets of resamples of the process: vectorize *that.*